# General functional form of Euler-Lagrange function for assumption on the form of solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Assume that we have Euler-Lagrange equation for $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$. By solution I will mean a function $x: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the following differential equation.

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{x}} f(x(t),\dot{x}(t),t) \right) (t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( f(x(t), \dot{x}(t), t) \right) (t)$$

Let us assume that if $x(t)$ is a solution then for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$ it is true that $\hat{x}(t) = x(t) + st$ is a solution.

Is there something that can be said about $f$? I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Why don't you let $$x \mapsto x + st \implies \dot{x} \mapsto \dot{x} + s$$ in your ELE and see what happens?

Comment: @Mattos I did exactly what you said but I wasn't able to see anything, sorry

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/485060/2451